# Angular application - Memory leak when using Painterro and mounting multiple images in queue

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using **[Painterro](https://github.com/devforth/painterro)** that I have embedded in my Angular application in one of the components.
I have a queue/list of images that are fetched from a remote server and the user have the possibility to add annotation on those images using *Painterro*.
Every time the user click next a new image is loaded to ***Painterro***.
My issue:

Even if no annotation is made on the current image the memory increase very quickly until the browser crash.

I'm my component Constructor I'm initializing the **Painterro** like this

```
 initPainterro() {
this.painterro = Painterro({
  saveHandler: (image, done) => {
    this.pdfReaderService.pdfPagesAsImages[this.pdfReaderService.currentPage.value] = image.asDataURL();
    done(false);
  },
  hiddenTools: ['crop', 'open', 'close', 'pixelize', 'eraser', 'resizeScale', 'resizeResize', 'redo', 'save'],
  language: 'he',
  colorScheme: {
    main: '#004582',
    control: '#ec8617',
    activeControl: '#a95710',
    controlContent: '#002e65'
}
});
```

}

then I'm attaching the painterro to an HTML element of my htmlTemplate

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
// this.elm.nativeElement.appendChild(this.painterro.holderEl);
```

}

and every time the user clicks next to load images on **Painterro**
I'm using this.painterro.show method to mount the current image.

```
this.painterro.show(this.pdfReaderService.pdfPagesAsImages[this.currentPage]);
```

I didn't find a way to unmount the previous image and release memory.
The Painterro clear() and hide() does not clear the memory.

Is there a way to release memory on previous mounted images on Painterro?

thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure leak is in painterro? Not in pdf related staff? Could you please give an idea what leaks by inspecting memory ussage in chrome devtools? Also as creater of painterro I would appreciate if you would create such issues on github, so me and other painterro developers will be able to find them(googled stackoverflow accidently)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using Painterro Angular, please follow the official integration hint, created by me as I am creator of Painterro : [How to add Painterro into Angular app](https://hinty.io/devforth/how-to-add-painterro-into-angular-app/)

No memory leaks are detected if you are using this way.